# Expo React Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo, use-effect

I'm new to react native and was following a tutorial on medium about how to connect with firebase auth. Everything seems to work fine, but I keep getting this warning below:

Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

I pretty much did exactly what was said in the tutorial and tried out a few other things to fix it, but nothing seems to work. Here is the code it's pointing the error to:

```
    let currentUserUID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => { 
        getUserInfo();
      })

      async function getUserInfo(){
        try {
          let doc = await firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection('users')
            .doc(currentUserUID)
            .get();
  
          if (!doc.exists){
            Alert.alert('No user data found!')
          } else {
            let dataObj = doc.data();
            setFirstName(dataObj.firstName)
          }
        } catch (err){
        Alert.alert('There is an error.', err.message)
        }
      }
```

It would be great if anyone could help me fix this problem and explain what exactly has gone wrong.

This is the [link](https://medium.com/swlh/expo-firebase-authentication-cloud-firestore-using-async-await-react-hooks-700920ad4b2b) to the tutorial I was following:

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are potentially enqueueing a state update *after* a component has unmounted. Since you are accessing your firestore directly, asynchronously, you can use a React ref to track if the component is still mounted *before* enqueuing the update.

```
const isMountedRef = React.ref(null);

useEffect(() => {
  isMountedRef.current = true;               // set true when mounted
  return () => isMountedRef.current = false; // clear when unmounted
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  async function getUserInfo(){
    try {
      let doc = await firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .doc(currentUserUID)
        .get();

      if (!doc.exists){
        Alert.alert('No user data found!')
      } else {
        let dataObj = doc.data();
        if (isMountedRef.current) { // <-- check if still mounted
          setFirstName(dataObj.firstName);
        }
      }
    } catch (err){
      Alert.alert('There is an error.', err.message)
    }
  }
  getUserInfo();
}, []); // <-- include dependency array, empty to run once when mounting
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `getInfoUser()` function is `async`. You should do something like this in `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(async () => { await getUserInfo(); }, [])
```

As a second argument in `useEffect` use the dependency array. Using the dependency array is equivalent  with `componentDidMount`.

Your effect will take place only once when the component is first rendered. Additionally there are cases when you need to provide a cleanup function in `useEffect` something like this:

```
return () => { 
   //do something or cancel a subscription
}
```

Comment: `useEffect` hook callbacks can't be `async`, that is why `getUserInfo` is declared separately and invoked *in* the hook callback. This isn't much of an answer as you've basically said to do the same thing the React warning already stated to do.